# BASH: Compare related entries in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have 3 files with md5 sums that I would like to compare. I was thinking of initially sorting the files and comparing them line by line. However, there are occasionally missing entries in one or more files. Fortunately, the package names are included with the md5 sums on the same row like this:

```
FILE 1: 
pkg1 md5sum1
pkg2 md5sum2 (this one might not be located in FILE 2, but is in FILE 3, as an example) 
etc....
```

How can I compare the md5sums of the packages that are present in ALL files (printing "match" or "mismatch") and output "missing" if not found in all files?

**EDIT:**

A sample output could be:

```
pkg1 w14r1w4r w14r1w4r w14r1w4r match
pkg2 t432t432 t432t432 t432t432 match
pkg3 r321     asdf     asdf     mismatch
pkg4 12341234                   mismatch
```

The first column is a list of all package names
The second, third, and fourth show the md5 sums for files 1-3
The last column shows match only if all 3 are the same

**EDIT2:**

If the 1st input file had an extra column (3rd), could we add this to the output file?

```
pkg1 md5sum1 string1  
pkg2 md5sum2 string2
```

The output would then be

```
pkg1 string1 w14r1w4r w14r1w4r w14r1w4r match
pkg2 string2 t432t432 t432t432 t432t432 match
pkg3 string3 r321     asdf     asdf     mismatch
pkg4 string4 12341234                   mismatch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no duplicated pacakge name in each file, you can run this:

```
awk '{a[$1 FS $2]++}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]==3?"match":"mismatch"}' file*
```

Here is the test result.

```
$ cat file1
pkg1 md5sum1
pkg2 md5sum2

$ cat file2
pkg1 md5sum1
pkg2 md5sum2
pkg1 md5sum3
pkg2 md5sum4

$ cat file3
pkg1 md5sum1
pkg2 md5sum2
pkg1 md5sum3

$ awk '{a[$1 FS $2]++}END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]==3?"match":"mismatch"}' file1 file2 file3
pkg2 md5sum2 match
pkg1 md5sum1 match
pkg2 md5sum4 mismatch
pkg1 md5sum3 mismatch
```

With the new edition, Here is the updated code:

```
awk '{a[FILENAME FS $1]=$2;b[FILENAME]++;c[$1]}
END{ for (i in c)
       { printf i;delete d
         for (j in b)
           { printf "%20s",a[j FS i];d[a[j FS i]]}
         printf "\t%s\n", (length(d)>1)?"mismatch":"match"
       }
    }' file1 file2 file3

pkg1            w14r1w4r            w14r1w4r            w14r1w4r        match
pkg2            t432t432            t432t432            t432t432        match
pkg3                r321                asdf                asdf        mismatch
pkg4            12341234                                                mismatch
```

Comment: Thanks to vote. I read the whole `The GNU Awk User's Guide` several times. http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/

Comment: `i` contains a row with "md5sum package match/mismatch". How do I know which md5sum is in the row? It's the last file right? actually, would it be possible to print out all three md5 sums regardless of match and then print whether it matched or not? so it would be "md5sum4 md5sum4 md5sum4 package4 match/mismatch"

Comment: Can you provide detail expect output from my sample three files?

Comment: This is really close. I get `md5sum pk1 pk1 pk1 match`. I think I just need to reverse the columns for the matching, and I'm good. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry last request. If the inputs had another column how can I add a column to the output after the pkg column?

Comment: you need provide the sample file

Comment: Sorry to bring this back, but what is the array d?

Comment: Array d is a temp array, used to count the numbers if the package has same md5 in same package. If it is 1 , that means all same, one value. If more than 1, that means there are at least two value in one package, then marks it mismatch. In the beginning, tt need be cleaned in "for loop"  for each package.